# Can't left join data to a temporary table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm trying to join some data onto the right side of a temporary table, but its not function as expected - when I left join it on, its not keeping only the rows on the left...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wploc
SELECT wp.name wpname, wp.id wpid, l.name lname, l.id lid 
FROM workplaces wp
JOIN locations l ON wp.id = l.workplace_id
ORDER BY wp.id;

SELECT * from wploc
```

This gives 390 results - the only ones I want to return, and I want to join onto the side a few more results from a different table, however when I do, I get all of the results from the table on the right:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wploc
SELECT wp.name wpname, wp.id wpid, l.name lname, l.id lid 
FROM workplaces wp
JOIN locations l ON wp.id = l.workplace_id
ORDER BY wp.id;

SELECT * from wploc
LEFT JOIN employees e ON wploc.lid = e.location_id
```

This gives all of the results from the `e` table as if I'm right joining it to the `workplaces` table.

How do I have `e` results only show up for the values already in `wploc` (ie the 390 results from where I created the temp table above)?

Comment: "This gives all of the results from the e table". It gives all the results that satisfy the join condition. That's how it is supposed to work. What did you want to happen? If you say what you want, we can tell you how to achieve that.

Comment: Do you have duplicate e.location_id values? Do you think you're getting the wrong result because there are more than 390 rows?

Comment: Can you give us a few example rows that demonstrate the problem? Something we can run for ourselves. You could even make a http://sqlfiddle.com showing the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't you just for the second query, reverse the tables and drop the `LEFT`? I.E. `SELECT * FROM employees JOIN wploc ON wploc.lid = employees.location_id`... And if you don't need the temp table anywhere else you could `SELECT * FROM employees e JOIN ( <first query> ) w ON w.lid = e.location_id` ...or am I missing something?

Comment: @DaveRandom that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @Andypandy What happens instead? Please can you show a couple of rows from your temporary table, and a couple more rows from the `employees` table, some which should be included in the result and some that shouldn't